# Preserve SQL with CodeSmith

Tags: sql, codesmith

How would I create a procedure with a PRESERVE region like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RunSQL
AS

--region Custom processing
--endregion

SELECT * FROM SomeTable

GO
```

Comment: To format code, including SQL, select it in the editor and press Control-K.

Answer (score 0):

For T-SQL your code would need to look like this:

RegionNameRegex should be set to ^[ \t]*[ \s]*"?(?i:Custom)"?;
Language should be set to "T-SQL";

Your regions should look like this:

--region Custom Parameters

--endregion

I have created a sample template located [here](http://community.codesmithtools.com/forums/p/10847/41407.aspx#41407).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski